# UITableView covers/hides image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

[image]

I want to make 2 `images` above my `tableView` - one `image` on the top and one on the bottom of the view. Like on the picture. I succeed with the `image` on the top (when I scroll the `tableView`, it scrolls under the image), however, the `image` on the bottom just doesn't appear.
What I did, I just resized the `tableView` and made it shorter on the top and bottom and added `UIImageView's`. But on the bottom, there is no `image`. I also tried to do it in code:

```
CGRect flagsFrame = CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 11);

UIImageView *bottomFlags = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:flagsFrame];
bottomFlags.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flags_down"];

[self.view addSubview:bottomFlags];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bottomFlags];
```

But nothing happens. Why there is no picture ? Looks like `tableView` covers the image or something.

Thank you !

**UPD:**

```
<UIWindow: 0x1be340; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x1be430>>
   | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1c0d00; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0da0>>
   |    | <UITransitionView: 0x1c1040; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c1410>>
   |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x1ca7a0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ca0b0>>
   |    |    |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1c5bf0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5c40>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x1c5fa0; frame = (0 0; 320 431); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c4da0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x108ff0; frame = (0 64; 320 367); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x109020>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1d43f0; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x13bce0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x13bd10; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x140fa0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0x9ec800; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x19cda0>; contentOffset: {0, 4165.5}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x10f5b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4097; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10b1e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x10f510; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c330>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x19eae0; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x125990>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10e9b0; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x128fe0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10f6c0; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x109620>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x115880; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x18d1e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x13ba00; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Слиток'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x117da0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x13eef0; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = 'Бесценно'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x126be0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10e350; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x117c30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x109ab0; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10d080>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x191090; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11b880>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10e2e0; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x10e310>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x1ca8b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4172; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11cee0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x11e610; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5da0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1dd650; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11d140>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x117d50; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x143680>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1183f0; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x16e8a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x130740; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c170>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x116b70; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Бонго'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10cc60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x115d80; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = '$15 - $120'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x115bb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12e9c0; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x143620>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x11e580; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15a240>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x11f520; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1dd1d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x11e350; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x118540>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x11c420; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4247; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1912b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x112f10; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11e230>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x117aa0; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x109940>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1decf0; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x123b60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x115c60; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x7275af0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10b7c0; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x101330>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x128e70; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Кресло массажер'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x117520>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x10e3b0; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = '$10 - $75'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x104c50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x18dc70; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10f270>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x112e80; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11ceb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x111890; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11e6b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x114480; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x11d110>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x115fc0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4322; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x125960>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x10ceb0; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x116220>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x11e280; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11e2b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10edb0; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ede0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x11c540; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x1179a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x112940; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10e530>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x111090; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Громкоговоритель'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x110a30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1423c0; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = '$10 - $75'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11c5a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x130880; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x11b8b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x10d650; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1910f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10a9a0; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10e4d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x117a00; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x117a30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x12d010; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4397; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x123b30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x111640; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f2260>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1116a0; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ebf0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10ec20; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ec50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x10c100; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x10f330>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x11b8e0; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1185b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x115f50; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Перочиный ножик'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x109820>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x115d10; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = '$15 - $80'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1f22e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x112900; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10ce80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x10f470; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ca720>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10dee0; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10df20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x1125d0; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x118100>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <CustomCell: 0x11c310; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 4472; 320 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x11ce00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x10b580; frame = (9 0; 302 75); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x155850>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x155880; frame = (1 0; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1128d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x10bb80; frame = (1 74; 300 1); hidden = YES; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10bbb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x11cc70; frame = (10 0; 280 74); layer = <CALayer: 0x109b90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1dd5f0; frame = (70 10; 350 25); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1185e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x115ca0; frame = (70 10; 230 25); text = 'Игровая консоль'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x117c00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x162e10; frame = (70 40; 120 18); text = '$170 - $500'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10c140>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x10cc10; frame = (10 10; 50 50); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x173d10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x10bc90; frame = (280 0; 30 74); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x140a90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x109360; frame = (10 30; 10 13); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x10f740>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x118350; frame = (10 0; 300 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x118380>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x142450; frame = (0 360; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15dc80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x100b70; frame = (0 5608; 320 11); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x141f60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1d4d20; frame = (312 4427.5; 7 36); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d4d80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12ea90; frame = (0 0; 320 11); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x126aa0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x124eb0; frame = (0 -135; 320 90); text = 'В комплекте подарите деву...'; clipsToBounds = YES; hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x13ff90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x72763e0; frame = (126 -64; 64 64); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7275840>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationBar: 0x1c5c70; frame = (0 20; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5d60>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationBarBackground: 0x1c5f60; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5ff0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationItemView: 0x1c17c0; frame = (116 8; 88 27); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c1810>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationItemButtonView: 0x1c1840; frame = (5 7; 80 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x109560>>
   |    | <UITabBar: 0x1c0fe0; frame = (0 431; 320 49); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c10c0>>
   |    |    | <_UITabBarBackgroundView: 0x1c1290; frame = (0 0; 320 49); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c1320>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0x1c89e0; frame = (2 1; 103 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c9be0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSelectionIndicatorView: 0x1ca310; frame = (0 2; 103 44); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ca3a0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSwappableImageView: 0x1c9770; frame = (28 2; 48 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c82c0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0x1c9a40; frame = (27 34; 50 13); text = 'Giftopedia'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c9b50>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0x1ca9c0; frame = (109 1; 102 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c0c00>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSwappableImageView: 0x1c96a0; frame = (27 2; 48 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c9bb0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0x1c8100; frame = (24 34; 55 13); text = 'Избранное'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c9700>>
   |    |    | <UITabBarButton: 0x1ca4a0; frame = (215 1; 103 48); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1caff0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarSwappableImageView: 0x1c8830; frame = (27 2; 48 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cb0c0>>
   |    |    |    | <UITabBarButtonLabel: 0x1c8380; frame = (18 34; 66 13); text = 'Информация'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1bf790>>
```

Comment: Pause in the debugger.  Run this command: `po [[(id)UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.  Paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the `recursiveDescription`, I see two `UIImageView`s with size 320x11.  One is a sibling of the `UITableView`:

```
<UIImageView: 0x12ea90; frame = (0 0; 320 11); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x126aa0>>
```

This image view's origin is at (0,0), so I deduce that it is the top image view.  It is listed after the `UITableView` in the output, which means that it is above the table view in the stacking order - it is “closer” to the user's eye and will be drawn on top of the table view.

The other image view with size 320x11 is listed as a subview of the table view:

```
<UIImageView: 0x100b70; frame = (0 5608; 320 11); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x141f60>>
```

So it appears to me that you are adding the bottom image view as a subview of the table view, but you need add it as a sibling of the table view.  You need to add it as a subview of the table view's superview.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your `recursiveDescription` output.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried this:
`[myTableView.superview addSubview:bottomFlags];`
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## If you want the images to stay on top of the table

If you want the images onto of the UItableView consistently then place the UITableView and the two header/footer views as subviews of the same UIView and bring the header/footer views to the front. The trick would be to turn off their `userInteraction` to touches go through them to the `UITableView` below.

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
[container addSubview:tableView];
[container addSubview:headerView];
[container addSubview:footerView];

headerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
footerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

## If you want the images to scroll with the table

You should use `tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView` to set UIViews at the top and bottom of your UITableView instances.

Comment: Sounds nice, but I don't want to make my images scrolling with tableView.

Answer (score 0):

it seem there is a little problem in this line:

`bottomFlags.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flags_down"];`

**try to add an extension for the image's name** (`.png`), otherwise the the `image` property will be `nil` and you won't see the image in your entire life.